# why does a custom button which added by code in UITabBarController.viewDidLoad doesn't response the selector

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I add a custom button to the tabBar in my `MyViewController.viewDidLoad(subclass of UITabBarController)`

But I find it doesn't response the selector.

If I delay one second to add button(`in DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter closure`) ,it works OK.

I think it's not the right way to resolve it.

```swift
func addButton() {
        let button = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom)
        button.bounds = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:30,height:30);
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        button.center = CGPoint(x:self.tabBar.frame.size.width/2, y:self.tabBar.frame.size.height/2 - 20);
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(click(button:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
        tabBar.addSubview(button)
    }
```

Comment: Where are you calling this method?

Comment: in `override func viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Can you add the code for the function `click(button:)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added button to `UITabBar` of `UITabBarController` as half of part of the button would appear above the Tabbar and half of below the Tabbar as per frame.

[image: Tabbar custode button]

So I guess you will not get click on part of that button which is out of Tabbar(above Tabbar) would not get touch. I you will make button little big OR try to click with arrow in simulator, you will get idea.

If you need to have button at bottom but slightly upper, then please create custom Tabbar to achieve design like this. Or else you can add that button into `UITabBarController`’s view instead of Tabbar.

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.addButton()
    }

    func addButton() {
        let button = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom)
        button.bounds = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:50,height:50);  //1
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
         button.center = CGPoint(x:self.tabBar.frame.size.width/2, y:self.tabBar.frame.size.height/2 - 50 + self.tabBar.frame.origin.y);  //2
         button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(click(button:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

         button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.height/2
         button.layer.masksToBounds = false
         button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
         button.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
         button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 5.0)
         button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5

        //tabBar.addSubview(button)  //3
         self.view.addSubview(button). //4
    }

    @objc func click(button: UIButton) {
         print("Button get clicked")
    }
}
```

I have marked four things with commented by numbers at the end of lines, that you can make to your code and try.

[image: Button in TabBarController]